# Accessing Word fields and auto texts from embedded Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, embed

I have some Word documents/templates with embedded Excel sheets/charts. Is it possible from Excel VBA to access data (bookmark contents, fields, auto texts) that is stored in the Word document?

An example of data could be patient ID stored in a Word auto text.

The VBA code must be inside the embedded Excel, not in the Word template, as I can't modify this.

The VBA code will probably be launched by double-clicking the embedded sheet, then pressing a shortcut key, but this is not part of my question.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that the template containing the Excel sheet is only open once, and we know the name of the template. Does this help, can I perhaps use DDE to connect to the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub HelloWord()

Dim wordApp As Object

Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

MsgBox wordApp.Activedocument.FullName

End Sub
```

Once you've got a handle on the the wordApp, you can access all the objects in the model as normal.

The downvote might be because this doesn't sound like a very efficient solution - might it be better to get the Excel data into a Word document or format the Excel document in an acceptable way.  You're invoking two pretty chunky apps here to do one thing.

Comment: Try adding the above VBA code in the Excel spreadsheet, in case I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow when I get to work. As for my "solution", I don't have a choice; the template is given by our RIS system (AGFA impax), I have the possibility to add autotext containing e.g. an Excel sheet, from which I want to execute some code.

Comment: Your suggestion works, as long as I haven't got any other open word-files. 
`wordApp.Activedocument.AttachedTemplate` 

gives either the name "Normal.dot" or the template I want.
I probably should try to enumerate all Word instances

Comment: Sure, the `ActiveDocument.FullName` was just an example.  You can also use the wordApp.Documents collection.  (PS This post also just a chance to try the funky mini-Markdown formatting that @angelcool.net helped me with - thank you, am newbie)